# Running JavaScript in browser console vs bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, bookmarklet, developer-tools

I tried to run a simple code to replace strings in the body of an HTML page in JS.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/foo/g,"bar");
```

The above code runs fine in the browser console (tested in Firefox and Chrome), but when I run the same via a JavaScript bookmarklet with a prefix of `javascript:`, the page breaks, losing all its style elements.

I'm just curious why the code behaves differently as I thought the JS code run in console or via bookmarklets would be run in the same environment.

Comment: What happens id that the return value from your assignment is replacing the page content. You can add ";return false" at the end to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to realize what's going on here is to type `javascript:"Hello world"` into the  location bar and hitting enter. Note that the page content is replaced, even though you didn't touch the DOM.

That's because the return value of a bookmarklet is handed over to the page content, if it exists. And in this case, `(document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/foo/g,"bar"))` evaluates to the new `innerHTML`<sup>1</sup>. Which is just the `innerHTML` of the document body, so the stle information is lost when the entire document HTML is replaced.

Far better to do this:

```
javascript: ( function(){document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/foo/g,"bar") }()
```

which has the added bonus of making all your `var`s private. Or you can just tack on a `return false;` to the bookmarklet as @diegog suggested.

<sup>1. Not `undefined`, in Javascript the equality operator returns the value too, much to  the annoyance of those who mistype `==`.</sup>